# About the definition of the norm $||A||$ of a linear operator $A$ in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin.

For a linear operator $A \in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$, Rudin defined the norm $||A||$ of $A$ as follows:

$||A|| := \sup_{|x| \leq 1} |Ax|$.

Because I am new to the norm of a linear operator, I feel the following definition is more natural:

$||A|| := \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |A(e_i)|^2}$.

Can we replace $||A|| := \sup_{|x| \leq 1} |Ax|$ with $||A|| := \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |A(e_i)|^2}$ in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin?

Comment: Try it for $n=m$ and $A=\mathrm{id}$. I also don't feel that the alternative you propose is very natural; it depends on a choice of basis, whereas the norm of an operator should be an intrinsic property of that operator.

Comment: I believe the norm you proposed is called the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. In finite-dimensional spaces, it and the usual norm (and all other norms on $\mathbb R^m$) are equivalent in th sense of inducing the same topology. In infinite-dimensional spaces, they behave very differently. In particlar, there can be operators for which the operator norm $\sup_{|x|\leq 1}|Ax|$ is finite but the sum in the Hilbert-Schmidt norm diverges.

Comment: @Thorgott Although the proposed definition refeers to a particular basis, the result is (if I remember correctly) the same for all orthonormal bases.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you very much for your comment. I need to study more.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for your comment. I need to study more.